# What is runtime complexity of advance method for forward iterators?

Tags: c++11, iterator

I am curious about knowing time complexity of advance() for unordered map<> which as far as I know are forward iterators?

Answer (score 2):

[From cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance):

> ### Complexity
>
> Linear.
>
> However, if `InputIt` additionally meets the requirements of [*LegacyRandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), complexity is constant.